# Start dialog from View

Tags: android

I'm studying Android and became a little bit confused with my the following task..
In my application MainActivity uses class, that extends View.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    panel = new MyPanel(this);
    setContentView(panel);
    panel.requestFocus();
}
```

I have a menu with 3 items, that allows the user to draw on view some primitive figures. So, when user picks a figure I start  my Dialog Fragment to get some parameters for it. DialogFragment "communicates" with my MainActivity throught interface, that MainActivity implements and my DialogFragment declares. There's no problem! But the next thing in my task is to let user touch already drawn figure and dialog shoud appear with this figure's parameters so the user could change it and save. It's not a problem to detact a figure, but! my knowledges are not enough to start dialog from view or maybe someone would tell me how I can finish the task?  ...I thought about intenets(and start activity, not dialog), but what class is gonna receive new data? Oh, I'm definitely doing smth wrong, please, help me
Thank's a lot for yout time!!

Comment: Based on the description of what you're trying to do, [I bet taking a look at Dialogs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) will lead you in the right direction.

Comment: Andrew Schuste, the link you provided "said" "These classes(AlertDialog, DatePickerDialog, TimePickerDialog) define the style and structure for your dialog, but you should use a DialogFragment as a container for your dialog. " And I don't know how to get FaragmentManager from View

Comment: `FragmentManager` is actually something you get from your `Activity`.  All you call is `getFragmentManager()`.  The __Creating a Dialog Fragment__ section is particularly useful for getting started with a Dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You can set [onTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) to your view

Then, when the user touches the view you will get into [onTouch()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html#onTouch%28android.view.View,%20android.view.MotionEvent%29) of that listener.

From there you can call your Activity's method which will start the dialog. You will create that method, too.

Since you know everything about your view you will be able to pass that data to that method and to the dialog.

Comment: Maybe my qestion is too obviousm but how can I Activity's method from class, that extends View? I should pass it as a parameter to my View constractor? But I create instance of my View in onCreate of Activity, so my Activity is not created yet, and this, as parameter is a context, not activity

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you need if you want to show a dialog is a Context object.
You can retrieve it within a View subclass using getContext() method:

```
public class Panel extends View {
    ...
    public void showDialog() {
         AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());

         builder.setTitle(...);  
         ...

         builder.show();
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I use my layout, not builder to show my dialogs, and in Main activity in method show I needed fragment manager, how can I get it in View?

Comment: You can write a setActivity(Activity) method for your view in which you save the activity instance. Then you can obtain a fragment manager by calling activity.getFragmentManager(). Although not an elegant solution.

Comment: Áron Nemmondommegavezetéknevem, could you please tell me what I shoud write in myActivity trying to call the method setActivity(Activity) for my View? because if I write (in Activity) panel.setActivity(this) it will trasfer context but not Activity instance, am I right?

Comment: It will transfer the activity instance. Forgot to say that an activity instance can be used as a Context (activity is actually a context).

Comment: You can also obtain a FragmentManager from the activity instance.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to put onTouch method in my Activity, and it works just fine! Thank's a lot, guys!